# Pass a array value to another array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a Array.It has for example 10 rows.
I need to checka flg. if flag has value false it goes to array number one,if it have flag true it goes go array number 2.I'm trying something like this.

```
if (lista2[i].FLG_FALHA == true)
{
    listaInc[c] = lista2[i];
    i++;
    c++;
}
else
{
    listaAlr[o] = lista2[i];
    o++;
    i++;
}
```

This is where i declare the arrays.

```
 List<AcompanhamentoSiltIncDTO> lista2 = new List<AcompanhamentoSiltIncDTO>();
 List<AcompanhamentoSiltIncDTO> listaInc = new List<AcompanhamentoSiltIncDTO>();
 List<AcompanhamentoSiltIncDTO> listaAlr = new List<AcompanhamentoSiltIncDTO>();
```

I get this error,it's like the arrays are not initialized.

> "{"The index was out of range, it should be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. \ R \ nName parameter: index"}"

Comment: Those are not arrays but Lists. Use the Add() method.

Comment: Also, you are adding to the _same_ List in both the then and else branches. An  error you would probably not have made with some better naming of your variables.

Comment: When you get an error telling you an index needs to be less than the size of the collection, check *two things*: The value of the index, and the size of the collection. At least one of them is not what you think it is.

Comment: I 'ill try,its two list i trype wrong,i will correct above.

Answer (score 2):

You should call the `Add()` method of your list:

```
if (lista2[i].FLG_FALHA == true)
  listaInc.Add(lista2[i]);
else
  listaAlr.Add(lista2[i]);
```

Otherwise, since your `listaAlr` and `listaInc` have no element, you get cannot access element at position `o` : `listaInc[o]`

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because you got out of range of your array. Check out your indexes. But for this task I suggest you working with linq. It gives you a lot of good functionality.

And if you have "List<>" you need to add elements to this list with "Add" method.
So code will be the next:

```
if (lista2[i].FLG_FALHA == true)
{
    listaInc.Add(lista2[i]);
    i++;
}
else
{
    listaAlr.Add(lista2[i]);
    i++;
}
```

But as I said you may use LinQ.
Code will be the next:

```
listInc = lista2.Where(x => x.FLG_FALHA);
listAlr = lista2.Where(x => !x.FLG_FALHA);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with LINQ.

```
var listaInc = from n in lista2
                where n == true
                select n;

var listaAlr = from n in lista2
                where n == false
                select n;
```

Bits more, bits less, but that is what I would do.